# How to use my own in-app-products when i can't buy them with the developer account?

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

Is there a way to check for the play account to activate all available in-app products to use it by my own (and my family)? I.e. adding some play store email addresses or use the tester-accounts defined by the play developer console?

Regarding the in-app-billing developer guide to test i need to use a test account.
So far so good - but i don't want to have a test account on my phone forever, me and my family just want to use my own in-app-products for free.

Any way to do it?

This is how i check for purchased in-app-products:

```
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        // ...
        Purchase myPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_SOMETHING);
        if (myPurchase != null) {
            // activate all features
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If it's your app, how about just enabling the features with some code changes?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That way i need to maintain 2 versions of the app. I know i can check for the developer signature of the app but thats not what i am looking for. I would like to check if the google app store account is the publisher or a testing account.

Since i have recently found i am also not able to test the in-app purchase on my phone with another google account (it always tell me it can't be purchased with publisher account) i don't know how to use all my features by myself and my family. Looks like i need to test for the signature.

Comment: Ok, looks like it is not possible to give developer and friends special access to the app. So i have added a check for the debug signature to check if the app is being started on a developer device.